# Argumento não é numérico nem lógico: retornando NA

Tags: r

Pesquisando por resposta sobre o erro que me deparei ao tentar analisar dados no R, encontrei uma caso muito parecido, mas não idêntico ao que me deparei. Assim, resolvi escrever minha pergunta de maneira sistematizada.

ROTINA no R:

```
# pr é o nome do arquivo de dados, em .txt 
> str(pr)
'data.frame':   280 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Trat  : Factor w/ 17 levels "ta","tb","tb ",..: 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 3 3 2 ...
 $ Colocm: Factor w/ 159 levels "0.168","0.173",..: 158 53 34 57 38 53 13 2 8 24 ...
 $ Compcm: Factor w/ 73 levels "10","10.1","10.2",..: 73 30 29 38 42 30 31 36 26 35 ...
 $ NF    : int  7 4 7 2 11 4 6 5 4 7 ...
 $ CRcm  : Factor w/ 99 levels "10","10.2","10.5",..: 39 56 45 68 59 55 78 82 73 57 ...
 $ MFR   : Factor w/ 205 levels "1.34","1.57",..: 153 32 15 54 177 32 126 22 80 85 ...
 $ MFCg  : Factor w/ 52 levels "0.13","0.14",..: 29 1 1 27 16 1 18 6 1 9 ...
 $ MFFg  : Factor w/ 98 levels "0.0436","0.12",..: 83 28 47 11 58 28 54 21 40 27 ...
 $ MSRg  : Factor w/ 117 levels "0.3","0.32","0.34",..: 108 18 47 107 87 51 88 23 58 62 ...
 $ MSCg  : Factor w/ 178 levels "0.00854","0.00986",..: 169 11 131 84 14 12 102 19 9 31 ...
 $ MSFg  : Factor w/ 102 levels "0.0086","0.01206",..: 95 73 52 80 59 69 80 59 78 64 ...
```

PROBLEMA: Ao tentar examinar a média da variável "Colocm" me deparo com o problema abaixo.

> mean(pr$Colocm) # média aritmética do colo
>   [1] NA
>   Warning message:
>   In mean.default(pr$Colocm) :
>     argumento não é numérico nem lógico: retornando NA

COMENTÁRIO: Como são dez variáveis e necessito fazer a análise exploratória das mesmas, necessito compreender onde estou errando.

Tenho interesse em adotar o R como ferramenta de análise de dados experimentais, notadamente na área agronômica, mas a falta de experiência no uso do R tem tomado muito tempo com os muitos erros que surgem ao tentar usar esta ferramenta para análise de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, perceba que sua variável **$Colocm:** está como **Factor w/ 159 levels**, ou seja você precisa converte-lá para formato numérico, assim o R conseguirá entender que são valores numéricos e fará os cálculos que você precisa.

Antes da leitura do seu .txt coloque esse comando abaixo, isso evitará que o R crie os levels no seu BD.

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Prezado Fernando, seguirei sim, sua orientação. Gratidão pela ajuda e atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Além da sugestão do @Fernandes, que deve seguir, há outro problema. Se o R está a ler os valores como strings deverá haver valores não numéricos no ficheiro. Uma maneira de resolver isso é, depois de ler a base, correr

```
pr[-c(1, 4)] <- lapply(pr[-c(1, 4)], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Isto funciona mesmo que as colunas sejam de classe `factor`.
Depois poderá inspecionar as colunas de classe `numeric` para ver se há valores `NA`.
Caso haja, talvez seja também util inspecionar o ficheiro e ver quais os valores que estão a causar problemas. É possível desembaraçar-se deles logo na leitura com o argumento `na.strings`. Veja a página `help("read.table")` para ver como usar `na.strings`.

Comment: Prezado Rui, muito obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Rui! Sua sugestão funcionou, no caso do meu BD. O que antes era factor, passou a numeric e assim pude seguir a análise exploratória. Gratidão.